# Auto-layout pinning two subviews together

Tags: ios, autolayout

*Disclaimer: I'm comparably new to iOS development. This is my very first try on Auto-layout.*

I have a container `UIView` that contains one `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`

When I click on the `UIButton` in the bottom of the view controller, I'd want the `UIImageView` to disappear and `UILabel` to automatically go to the top.

*P.S. Please introduce me to some good resources to learn Auto-layout principles. Thank you*

[image]

Comment: Look at the WWDC 2012 session videos. There are 3 different ones that cover layout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out your starting and ending layout constraints, then you can animate it using this template:

```
// add/remove constraints here or even change the constants of a current constraint
[view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
    [view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Have a read of the [Cocoa AutoLayout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html)

Also watch the WWDC videos on AutoLayout. WWDC 2012 232 Auto Layout by Example is a great one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to

- define a constraint for the height of the image view;
- define an `IBOutlet` for that constraint; and
- when you tap on the button, set the `constant` for that imageview's height constraint to be 0, and then do the `layoutIfNeeded` as recommended by bandejapaisa:

  ```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
      [view layoutIfNeeded];
  }];
  ```

If all of your other constraints are defined properly (e.g. the button's top constraint is to the image view and *not* the superview, the button has no bottom constraint to the superview, etc.), then this should yield the desired effect. Also, if you change the image view's `contentMode` to something like "aspect fill", then make sure you define the image view to clip subviews (so that you don't have the image spilling outside of the zero height image view).